# Display issue on question without any changes being made

Tags: bug, display-math-mode

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3447090/727383) previously displayed properly, and hasn't been edited since. I.e. it looked fine yesterday when I provided the bounty. Also, compare [how it appears in the revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3447090/revisions), this is what it looked like yesterday (in particular look at the scrolling box for the long fraction).

I verified that it isn't just on my computer with users in the math stack exchange chat room. The only change that I can think of is that I awarded it a bounty, which may give the answer special display permissions.

In particular, the giant fraction previously appeared as a text box, that had a scroll bar on it, rather than just displaying the entire fraction.

Questions:

1. Did stack exchange make a display change?
2. Does awarding bounties alter display permissions?
3. Is how a question displays independent of time (without any changes to the platform)

See this picture for posterity (you'll have to click it):
[image: Zoomed out picture of the answer being displayed way outside of the answer box.].

Comment: [See Über-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339651/strange-overlapping-post-layout-and-sidebar).

Comment: Apparently a buggy css was deployed.

Comment: Thanks for filling me in @DanielFischer

Should I delete this meta question or leave it for posterity?

Comment: I'd leave it here for the moment, maybe others intending to post about the issue will see yours. If things are back to normal tomorrow (apparently things are [supposed to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339651/strange-overlapping-post-layout-and-sidebar#comment1134392_339662), and it's only a matter of when the cache updates), you can delete it then. Or keep it if you want.